# MVC Create not adding to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using the automatically generated create action and it works fine. However When I use attribute based routing to one of the other Actions nothing gets added to my database it will just send me straight back to a blank form. I have put a breakpoint at the beginning of the POST for Create and it never gets reached after pressing Submit.

Is there a restriction with attribute based routing that I don't know of?

***EDIT:***

**I forgot to mention that the attribute based routing is not on the create Action but only on the Details Action, however this affect the Create Action**

```
    // GET: /Movies/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Movies/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Column Names")] Movies movies)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movies);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(movies);
    }
```

Comment: You need to include the action method and view.

Comment: @niko619 I did not see **Attribute Routes** in Action methods. Did you place **Attribute Routes** in **Controller**? As Stephen said, you need to post your **Views** *(and **Controller** if Attribute Routes are in Controller)*?

Comment: Yes it is in the Controller. I'm new to this. How would I include the Views & Controller?

Comment: So I got this working by adding another Route to the Create and the POST create